# How to get value from HTML user input in django view?

Tags: javascript, html, django

Hello everyone I have an HTML form as follows:
and after clicking on post i am redirecting it to views.py. can any one tell me how to get the field values of all the fields of the form into views.py.
here's the output
i want the field value in key value pair like shown in above pic i.e. API=hello&Area=hello1 so on...

i know we can do that using this
if html:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="param">TAF Parameter</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inputdata_API" class="form-control" id="inputapi_param" value="API" readonly>
                </div>
```

and view:

```
def register(request):
    api = request.GET.get['inputdata_API']
```

But in that case i have to write each and every input name in my view

Answer (score 0):

**To get form input without individual access, Django provide [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)**

For resume :

1. Define a model to store your form informations

   class MyModel(models.Model):
   api = models.CharField()
   # ...
2. Define a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) linked to the previous model

   ```
    from django import forms

    class MyModelForm(forms.Form):
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ['api', # all others fields you want to display]
   ```
3. In the `views.py`

   ```
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    from django.shortcuts import redirect

    def register(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
             # Instanciate the form with posted data
             form = MyModelFor(request.POST)
             # Check if form is valid
             if form.is_valid:
                 # Create a new MyModel object if the form is valid
                 form.save()  # This is the most benefit line, save you from request.POST['field_name'] 
                 # You can eventually return to the same page
                 return redirect('.') 
             else:  # The form is invalid return a json response
                 return JsonResponse({"Error": "Form is invalid"}, status=400)
   ```
4. At the end render the form fields in the template like this :

   ```
     <form action="{% url 'url_to_register' %}" method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
     </form>
   ```

**But the downside of this approach is the style of the form on the frontend :**
You need to add some Bootstrap class for example in the right place to make it nice to look, it is a a counterpart...

Django form [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/).

Comment: Hey, i dont want any model for my html user input

Comment: I just want the html userinput values in my view

Comment: Use then `request.POST.get('field_name')` ! I just show you how to deal with large form in Django easily.